# get a random number and check if mysql id exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to generate a random number and search for the entry by id  in a mysql database I select and if this id does not exist in the database, search for a new one, as long as the script finds one.Then output some line form this row. sounds easy but don't know how to handle the errors.

found this one:

```
    SELECT name, address, ROUND(100.0 + 400.0 * RAND()) AS random_number
    FROM users
```

but here isn't the error handler included. Can you help here?

Comment: This seems like a very strange use case. Do you perhaps just want one random record?

Comment: no i want to show other entries for the user  like "view other places in London:" and for that i searche for other random entries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want one random record you can use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT name, address FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This will give you one random user.

Comment: ahh very good. i tried to add another variable to the sql argument but its not working. 



`code`"SELECT name, id FROM locations ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 WHERE city='".$city."';"`code`

Comment: Specify which column do u want it to be randomzied by. RAND(`id`)

Comment: @Crag: Your query should be `SELECT name, id FROM locations WHERE city='$city' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. And you should go with Prepared Statement to bind runtime inputs.

Comment: @JacobCohen: No. `Rand( id )` always returns same value.

Comment: Do you have only 1 row?

Comment: Ah nvm, the reason your statment didnt work is because your LIMIT and ORDER BY was before the WHERE.